# Compatibility level check

Tags: sql-server, performance

To prevent memory grant (excessive) problems I want to change my DB compatibility level to 150

How can I be sure I won’t have a problem ?

Is there any script/tool to check my DB for 150?

Comment: What kind of problem do you fear? The script is to verify if your db is gonna face any problem if you change the compatibility level to 150 or to check if the DB was configured with the compatibility level 150?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended process to increase your database compatibility level is documented here:

[image]

[Change the Database Compatibility Level and use the Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/change-the-database-compatibility-mode-and-use-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15)